# Discretize the columns first - Apriori in R

Tags: r

I extracted this data from a file:

```
forests<-read.table("~/Desktop/f.txt", header = FALSE, sep = " ", fill = TRUE)

library(arules) //after installing the package
```

I get an error when I type

```
 forests<- apriori(forests, parameter = list(support=0.3))
```

> Error in asMethod(object) :    column(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
>   10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,
>   27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43,
>   44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
>   61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77,
>   78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85 not logical or a factor. Discretize the
>   columns first.

I tried `discritize(forests)`.  It still doesn't work.

`itemFrequencyPlot(forests)` also gives an error saying unable to find inherited method.

Have I imported the data incorrectly?

Comment: These numbers indicate id's and how many times they appear.

Comment: I don't what kind of data you have, but if it is character than setting to factor is already enough. Otherwise you'll have to discretize the numerical columns first. Nonetheless, you should give us some kind of sample data so we can see what your data looks like. Perhaps you should also try your code first on a smaller dataset with less variables to see if you can get it working with that.

Comment: Row1 : 1 4 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 20 24 35 37 39 45 61 62 65 75 77 79 84 86 87 88 92 95 105 106 116 118 119 126 127 128 130 135 137 138 139 143 146 150 154 155 158 160 163 164 169 172 175 177 180 182 183 188 190 191 192 195 199 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  

Rw2: 1 2 4 7 8 9 11 13 14 20 21 22 24 31 33 34 35 37 40 43 45 59 61 62 64 65 67 72 74 75 82 84 86 87 89 91 92 93 97 103 104 105 110 111 113 115 116 119 122 126 127 128 130 132 133 138 139 140 143 145 146 147 148 151 156 158 159 163 164 166 167 171 172 173 180 182 183 184 191 192 197 200 202 203 204 NA

Comment: Remove some superfluous text.